# nginx upstream and the backup parameter

Tags: nginx

I would like to know the purpose of the `backup` parameter in nginx `upstream` module. Specifically, what would be effect of having the following configuration without `backup`?

```
server server1:9080 weight=1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=120s;
server server2:9080 weight=1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=120s backup;
```

The documentation states:

> backup marks the server as a backup server. It will be passed requests when the primary servers are unavailable.

Wouldn't the same thing happen without the `backup` statement? If `server1` fails, the requests will be sent to `server2` during the period of 120s anyway. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Without `backup` nginx will distribute request between two servers, so both of them will receive about a half of request.

Comment: I see. In the case that `server1` is down, nginx will try to reach it every 120s, and if it back up, it will start routing all requests to `server1`?